# Rpi2 - Samba with multiple clients performance

Tags: streaming-video, samba

I'd like to use Rpi as home NAS, I have already problems using XBMC and samba. Making it really slow to work with HD connected with Rpi. Now I want to try plain raspbian with Samba to serve files (watching movies) from connected HD for multiple PCs, maybe it will be quicker.

Is it possible to serve multiple files (up to 3) from Rpi at the same time?

Rpi is connected to 100Mb ethernet.

Any hints how to make it faster? HD formatting, another OS, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Rpi is connected to 100Mb ethernet.

Right, and this shares a bus with the USB connection that your hard drive is on.  Realistically, [the maximum throughput on the bus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB#USB_2.0) is 35 MB/s.

That's okay, because 100 Mbps is only 12 MB/s, so you should, optimally in theory, be able to transfer at that rate from the drive.

In reality, I have not seen anyone claim much more than half this with regard to the pi, i.e., 6-8 MB/s.  If the drive is NTFS formatted, that will probably slow things down.  Samba may also not been the fastest mediator.

So it should still not be impossible to serve 3 files at 1 MB/s each, which will cover [some but not all](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_rate#Video) HD bitrates.  Again, I'd take this as a best case scenario.

Comment: great analysis, anyway would changing the formating of HD help(ie. to ext fs) help a lot?

Comment: You'd have to test that (just transfer some gigabyte size things as fast as you can), but I have heard the NTFS drivers on linux can be bottlenecks in that they require a lot of CPU, so if you are doing multiple things at once they must contend with each other that way.  Watching the CPU load will give you a clue about that -- you should be able to max out the network connection doing simple transfers without using much CPU.  If you are, then something is up.